# Writing to a firebase table in react native

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, mobile

I have a react native android app connected to firebase. One of the tables, 'Content', has the following schema:
[firebase schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXgKl.png)

I have a 'Post It!' button, and when pressed I want a user's post to be written to this Firebase table.

```
<Button
  style={{height: 50, width: 20, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 10}}
  title="Post It!"
  color='blue'
  onPress={this.uploadTextPost}
/>
```

The 'uploadTextPost' function looks like this:

```
  uploadTextPost() {
    this.rootRef('Content/qwa4').set({
      Author: this.state.author,
      Content_Text: this.state.textPostContent,
      Content_Title: this.state.title,
      Content_Type: 'TEXT',
      Downvotes: this.state.downvotes,
      Plot_Point: this.state.textPlotPoint,
      Timestamp: this.state.timestamp,
      Upvotes: this.state.upvotes
    });
  }
```

which accesses this.state:

```
this.rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

    this.state = {
      author: 'John JJ James',
      textBookSubject: 'na',
      textPlotPoint: 'na',
      textPostContent: 'na',
      upvotes: 0,
      downvotes: 0,
      title: 'Hopefully this works',
      timestamp: '08/18/2018 19:59:23',
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: 'first', title: 'Text Post' },
        { key: 'second', title: 'Art Post' },
        { key: 'third', title: 'Request'},
      ],
    };
  }
```

However, when I test it in my Android emulator by pressing the 'Post It' button, *nothing* populates the database. Any idea why?

Comment: Two things: (1) could you post a bit more code so we can make sure this.rootRef does what you intend it to? and (2) make sure in the remote debugger there isn't anything wrong in the request

Comment: @JasonKao I added the 'rootRef' variable to the constructor. There are no error messages in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: just posted a suggested fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firebase.database().ref(PATH)` returns a reference of some arbitrary path. By setting `this.rootRef` to `firebase.database.ref()`, you are making `this.rootRef` the root Reference of the database (which is not a callable function).

If you don't want to change `uploadTextPost()`, you can change this.rootRef to `firebase.database.ref`, in which case calling `this.rootRef('Content/qwa4')` would be the equivalent of calling `firebase.database.ref('Content/qwa4')`.

However, I would advise you to keep `this.rootRef` as the actual root reference of the database (so `this.rootRef = firebase.database.ref()`). In this case, `uploadTextPost()` should be:

```
uploadTextPost() = {
  this.rootRef.child('Content/qwa4').set(...);
}
```

Check out the documentation of [`firebase.database.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) for why the `child` method works here.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much Jason really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)